How can I send a push notification directly from my SwiftUI app using Firebase, without relying on the Firebase website?
While looking up many ways to perform this action, it seems like most people do it from using the Firebase website. What I'm trying to do is to have a push notification happen from the SwiftUI app itself using Firebase.
What I am asking is instead of relying on the Firebase website and inputting the push notification there, can I reliably do it from a SwiftUI app instead?
Here's the example that does not work:

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import Combine

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {

    var window: UIWindow?
    @Published var fcmToken: String?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { _, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.fcmToken = fcmToken
        }
        print("FCM registration token: \(fcmToken ?? "")")
    }
}



import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.sendPushNotification()
        }) {
            Text("Send Push Notification")
        }
    }
    
    func sendPushNotification() {
        guard let token = appDelegate.fcmToken else {
            print("FCM token not available")
            return
        }

        let urlString = "https://NOT_LETTING_SERVER_GET_SHOWN.json"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        let body: [String: Any] = ["token": token]
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            if let data = data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response: \(responseString)")
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
}
`


import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@main
struct TestingPushNotesApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .environmentObject(appDelegate)
    }
}


As I kept trying to find a method, none of them seem to work, or would require the use of the Firebase website.

There is no way to securely send messages from one device to another directly through Firebase Cloud Messaging. You can send a message through FCM by calling its API, but that requires a type of credentials that should only be used on a trusted environment - such as you development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.
Also see:

Device to device push notifications logic Swift IOS Firebase
How to send one to one message using Firebase Messaging
How to send Device to device notification by using FCM without using XMPP or any other script.?
How to send device to device messages using Firebase Cloud Messaging?

